# keras traindata shape is different from testdata shape but i use full conv network

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm using keras. When I train my network, I used 256*256*9 shape of the image, but I don't fix the height and weight. And my network is full conv network. But I test with a 512*512*9, I fail to test it because of shape. The function of keras seems cant be changed. I really don't know how to solve it, here is error log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "test9.py", line 19, in <module>
        predict = model.predict(img)   
File "/home/dingyuyang/.conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training. py", line 1147, in predict
        x, _, _ = self._standardize_user_data(x)   
File "/home/dingyuyang/.conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training. py", line 749, in _standardize_user_data
        exception_prefix='input')   
File  "/home/dingyuyang/.conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kera

s/engine/training_ utils.py", line 137, in standardize_input_data str(data_shape)) 

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have shape (256, 256, 9) but got array with shape (512, 512, 9)
```

Here is my test code:

```
model = load_model("weight9.h5")
img = scipy.io.loadmat('./bike_r_6.mat')
img = img['imghor'].astype("float32")
img = img / 255
img = np.transpose(img, (1, 2, 0))
img = np.reshape(img,(1,)+img.shape)
predict = model.predict(img)
print(predict.shape)
predict[predict>=0.7]=1
predict[predict<0.7]=0
predict = np.squeeze(predict)
predict = np.transpose(predict, (2, 0, 1))
name = '92mask.mat'
scipy.io.savemat(name, {'x': predict})
```

Here is my main network code:

```
def unet(pretrained_weights = None,input_size = (None,None,None)):
    inputs = Input(input_size)
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(inputs)
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool1)
.......
```

The imputshape is filled from main():

```
h, w ,d= org.shape
model = unet(input_size = (h,w,d))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is very normal that it is not working. Your model's input shape should be 256*256*9 but you are pushing a 512*512*9 in predict.
When you create your model in `model = unet(input_size = (h,w,d))` , you are setting the shape of the input being h,w,d. So any training examples in *fit* and validation/test in *predict* should follow the same shape.

If you have different shapes, you should provide a strategy, like cropping or reshaping your model's input

Comment: but i have run other code,their input-shape when training is different from their test-shape,becasue their network is full conv network?how can i get that?

Comment: @dingyuyang A full Convolutional network, is an architecture in which we have no fully connected layers. I can not see how it is related to the reshaping of the inputs?

Comment: https://github.com/JiahuiYu/generative_inpainting           like that ,it trained by 256*256*3 image,but it can test any shape image.

Comment: As I have mentioned above, it has nothing to do with **Full Convolutional** architecture. And as I have mentioned in the answer you need to crop or reshape your input. In the GitHub you have shared, they are obviously using **padding** which is a method to reshape( to a higher kernel size). Check the inpaint_ops.py and where the gen_conv function  is defined